# How should I handle searching through byte arrays in Java?

Tags: java, http, parsing, arrays

Preliminary: I am writting my own httpclient in Java. I am trying to parse out the contents of chunked encoding.

Here is my dilema: Since I am trying to parse out chunked http transfer encoding with a gzip payload there is a mix of ascii and binary. I can't just take the http resp content and convert it to a string and make use of StringUtils since the binary data can easily contain nil characters. So what I need to do is some basic things for parsing out each chunk and its chunk length (as per chunked transfer/HTTP/1.1 spec).

Are there any helpful ways of searching through byte arrays of binary/part ascii data for certain patterns (like a `CR` `LF`) (instead of just a single byte) ? Or must I write the for loops for this?

Comment: Note just because there is a CR LF does not mean it is necessarily text. Binary data could also have these byte sequences. What is in these chunk-encoded files ? That might help you solve the issue.

Comment: Java string can contain nil character. `"\0x".endsWith("x")` is `true`.

Comment: You should by the way never convert binary streams to character streams only because you'd like to parse them. CRLF is only 2 ASCII bytes. Just check for a 13 and a 10 behind each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thus, you basically need a `ChunkedInputStream`. [Google](http://google.com/search?q=%22class+chunkedinputstream+extends+inputstream%22) gives enough hints. [Apache HttpCore's](http://hc.apache.org/) variant is pretty concise. I'd suggest you to just use it rather than reinventing your own client.

Comment: Thanks, this will help + my io code was starting to get a bit crazy.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really want to implement your own HTTP client stack from the ground up, try a Google search for "+java +bytestring".  One of the first hits that I got was this [ByteString](http://www.hunnysoft.com/jmime/doc/com/hunnysoft/jmime/ByteString.html) class which would seem to do provide the kind of functionality you are asking for.

But I think @BalusC's approach is better.